# Can you set a variable in php to false?

Tags: php, syntax, boolean

Can you set a variable in php to false?

Can this code be correct:

```
if($jack = "Not tall"){

$jack = FALSE;

}
if(!jack){do whatever;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to compare values, make sure to have `==` for "is equal to", or `!=` "is not equal to". When you have one `=` then you are setting the variable and will always evaluate as true. [PHP Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
if($jack == "Not tall"){
  $jack = FALSE;
}
if(!$jack){
  // do whatever ...
}
```

And when dealing with variables, always make sure you have the `$` in the front. This is very basic php stuff.

Comment: I forgot to add the $. But you answered my question thanks.

Answer (score 0):

setting a value in if statement always return true because it will return current value.

```
echo ($jack = "Not tall")
```

it will print **"Not tall"** so it will return true

```
$jack = FALSE;
```

it will always set **false**.

```
if($jack == "Not tall")
  $jack = FALSE;
if(!jack){do whatever;}
```

[Differences between the Equality operator (==) and the Assignment operator (=)](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/differences-equality-operator-assignment-operator.html)